# Calculating lidR::rumple_index for polygons using raster::extract

Tags: lidar, extract, lidr

I have a raster (CHM) that I am using to calculate various vegetation metrics for a large set of polygons. See example below:

```
veg_metrics = function(x, na.rm) c(mean = mean(x, na.rm=na.rm), min = min(x, na.rm=na.rm), max = max(x, na.rm=na.rm))
output = extract(raster, polygons, fun = veg_metrics, sp = TRUE)
```

I am hoping to add rumple to the list of metrics using lidR::rumple_index(), but get the following error:

*Error: NULL is not numeric it is a NULL.*

**Any suggestions for how to code that?**

I am able to calculate rumple from the same CHM without using extract(), but since I have >1,500 polygons that I need to calculate it for (each of which has associated metadata) I am hoping to use extract().

Comment: Please report a reproducible example. I do not understand the question good enough to provide a correct anwser.

Comment: Thanks, I'll upload something shortly. Briefly, I'm wondering if it is possible to use rumple_index() as a user-defined function within extract(). And, if so, what the syntax would be for that.

Comment: No it is not possible. rumble index is expecting a matrix as input. extract is expecting a vector

Comment: Great, thanks for your help!